# RelationalDatabase in Mathematica 12

Tags: databases

My first attempt at using MMA's database capabilities appears to be a failure:

```
ref = DatabaseReference[FindFile["optiondb_tb_options.sql"]];
DatabaseConnect[ref]
```

[image]

So far so good.  But then:

```
RelationalDatabase[ref]
```

[image]

The database is a standard MySQL database and is not encrypted.

Comment: I use V 12 data base all the time. Never had problem. But I do not use the method you show to access the database. I use JDBC driver and `OpenSqlConnection` as described here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/ref/OpenSQLConnection.html  I use SQLite as my database btw.

Comment: The `.sql` file is not a database, it is a dump or a file that is needed to create one. You need a running MySQL server with your database already created and setup, not an `.sql` file. The only file-based db that is currently supported by the new relational db functionality is SQLite, but that is not an `.sql` file either. The fact that the connection returns `"Success"` on `.sql` file is probably a bug, that I will report.

Comment: @Nasser If you use DatabaseLink, this means that you don't use the new relational db functionality. These two are complementary and unrelated.

Comment: Thank you Leonid.  That MMA only currently works with SQLite is an issue I had not foreseen.  It is unhelpful that I am unable to locate any reference in the documentation spelling out which types of db MMA will interface to (although all the examples appear to be for SQLite).  Do you happen to know if the new relational db functionality will work with PostgreSQL?

Comment: According to "new in v12", MMA can connect to a MySQL db:   https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/relational-database-connectivity/connect-to-a-public-mysql-instance.html?product=language

Comment: *"That MMA only currently works with SQLite is an issue I had not foreseen"* - you did not interpret what I wrote correctly. MySQL is supported, but the `".sql"` script is **not** MySQL. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 10):

### General

The new relational databases functionality does currently support SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL, and the support for Oracle is coming very soon. There are a few steps one has to go through to expose the database as a source of entities in WL.

In all cases, the database must be prepared / exist before you try to connect. Please note that having `".sql"` files **does not cut it** - these files are on their own not a database, they are the scripts needed to create one.

For server-based database backends (all supported ones except SQLite are such), be sure to have a running db instance with connection information, such as

- the server (name or IP address)
- database port
- database name
- username
- password

available, before you try to connect. If the database is not administered by you, such information should be available to your sys. admin, so you will need to request it.

### Connecting to the database

The way to connect to server-based database backends (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL, Oracle - support for the latter coming very soon) - is to have the server set up and use either the connection url string or, alternatively, an assoc with the specs.

For MySQL, it may look like this. First, define a connection:

```
connectionMYSQL =  DatabaseReference[
  {
   "Backend" -> "mysql",
   "Port" -> 3306,
   "Host" -> "localhost",
   "Username" -> "test",
   "Password" -> "test",
   "Name" -> "classicmodels"
  }
]
```

Connection is an inert object, it doesn't do anything. Now, connect to the database  (`RelationalDatabase` constructor performs the connection and inspects the database structure, returning the inert `RelationalDatabase[...]` object that contains metadata about database structure):

```
rdb = RelationalDatabase@connectionMYSQL

(*  RelationalDatabase[Table count: 8 Backend: MySQL] *)
```

You can see which tables are in there:

```
rdb["Tables"]
(* 
   {
      productlines,orders,products,orderdetails,
      employees,payments,offices,customers
   }
*)
```

There are other properties you can extract from this object, but I will not get into that here.

### Creating and registering `EntityStore` object

Now you can create an entity store out of `RelationalDatabase` object:

```
es = EntityStore @ rdb

(* EntityStore[Type count: 8 RelationalDatabase: MySQL] *)
```

Finally, you register the entity store:

```
EntityRegister @ es

(* 
   {
      productlines,orders,products,orderdetails,
      employees,payments,offices,customers
   }
*)
```

### Running queries

Now you are ready to run queries. For example:

```
EntityValue[
  "offices", 
  {"officeCode", "addressLine1", "city", "state", "country"}
]

(* 
 {{"1", "100 Market Street", "San Francisco", "CA", "USA"}, 
  {"2", "1550 Court Place", "Boston", "MA", "USA"}, 
  {"3", "523 East 53rd Street", "NYC", "NY", "USA"}, 
  {"4","43 Rue Jouffroy D'abbans", "Paris", Missing["NotAvailable"],"France"}, 
  {"5", "4-1 Kioicho", "Tokyo", "Chiyoda-Ku", "Japan"}, 
  {"6", "5-11 Wentworth Avenue", "Sydney", Missing["NotAvailable"], "Australia"}, 
  {"7", "25 Old Broad Street", "London", Missing["NotAvailable"], "UK"}
 }
*)
```